# Enviar valores de Checkbox de un datatables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo un problema al enviar el valor de los `input` en estado `checked` a mi controlador, lamentablemente me envía solo los valores de la pagina en la que me encuentre en ese momento y no la de todas las paginas donde he seleccionado un `checkbox`, a lo que me refiero con paginas es porque estoy usando la paginación de `datatables`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>Ventas</h2>
        <form action="venta.php" method="POST">
            <table id="inventario" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Selección articulo</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>&nbsp;Cantidad</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;Marca</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Categoria</th>
                        <th><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;Precio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($articulos as $articulo): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="articulos[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $articulo['id']; ?>"><?php echo $articulo['nombre']; ?></label></td>
                        <td><?php echo $articulo['cantidad']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $articulo['categoria']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $articulo['marca']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo number_format($articulo['precio_u']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="vender" value="Vender">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#inventario').DataTable();
                var dataArr = [];
                 $('tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {      
                      dataArr.push($(this).find('input').eq(0).val());
                        console.log(dataArr);
                 });
        } );
    </script>
```

Como algunos pudieron apreciar he intentado hacer un script para recoger todos los valores y poderlos enviar a mi controlador sin embargo no logro realizarlo no soy muy bueno con el JS.

Encontre que alguien hizo este snippet para este problema sin embargo no se como complementarlo.

```
var rows = $(('#datatable')
   .rows({ 'search': 'applied' })
   .nodes()).filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');//busca todos los registros del datatable

rows.each(function(index,elem){
   //cada row es un tr
     console.log($('datatable').row(elem).data());
});
```

> De ser necesario usar ajax para enviar todos los valores de los checkbox seleccionados no tengo ningun problema.

Comment: Esta usando la paginacion que hace automáticamente datatables?

Comment: Asi es, estoy usando dicha paginacion de datatables, por defecto vienen 10 rows por pagina.

Comment: Es muy raro, tengo hecho algo parecido y no me sucedía ese problema, o nunca me di cuenta del "bug" lo voy a revisar y te vuelvo a comentar.

Comment: efectivamente pasa eso que dices, menos mal que leo este foro, lo voy a solucionar y luego te paso como lo hice.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, lamentablemente tengo que salir en muy poco tiempo y no voy a llegar a darte una respuesta adecuada (me voy de vacaciones), pero puedo guiarte para que lo puedas solucionar. primero no usar input checkbox, usar la libreria select de datatable. y luego podes ver cuales están seleccionados no importa en que página. (var cellsSelected = $(".datatable").rows({ selected: true }).data();), en particular yo cuando obtengo las filas seleccionadas hago un while para recorrerlas y agrego inputs hiddens al form, con jquery, y despues submiteo el form. Lamento no poder mostrarte el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo prometido es deuda, solucione el mismo problema de la siguiente manera:

Primero quitá los input de tipo checkbox de la tabla y deja solo el td vacio:

```
<form action="venta.php" method="post" id="form">
    <table id="inventario" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Selección articulo</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>&nbsp;Cantidad</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;Marca</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Categoria</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($articulos as $articulo): ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $articulo['cantidad']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $articulo['categoria']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $articulo['marca']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($articulo['precio_u']); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="vender" value="Vender" id="vender">
</form>
```

Agregar los enlaces de la libreria select de datatables:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

Para usar la librería lo hacemos de la siguiente manera, en este caso sobre el primer td de cada row.

```
var table = $('#inventario').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'multi', //'os' para seleccion unica 
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    }
});
```

En este punto ya deberiamos ver los inputs checkbox en la primer columna y tendriamos que poder seleccionarlos.

Luego para obtener los elementos seleccionados podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Primero al form le podes poner id=form para poder identificarlo y al botón le podes poner type="button" para que no se submitee automaticamente y id="vender" para capturar el evento click mas adelante (en el html de arriba estos cambios ya están aplicados).

Luego podrías capturar los elementos seleccionados al hacer click sobre el boton "vender" , agregarlos al formulario con inputs type="hidden" con los ids de esos elementos y submitear el form.

```
$('#vender').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
  var seleccionados = table.rows({ selected: true });
  
  if(!seleccionados.data().length)
    alert("No ha seleccionado ningún producto");
  else{
    seleccionados.every(function(key,data){
      console.log(this.data());

      $('<input>', {
          type: 'hidden',
          value: this.data()[1],
          name: 'ids[]'
      }).appendTo('#form');
      
      //$("#form").submit(); //submiteas el form
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Se agrego al código un comentario para diferenciar la selección múltiple de la única, se actualizaron las versiones de la librerías y se agrego un ejemplo funcional.

Acá dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#inventario').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi', //'os' para seleccion unica 
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        lengthMenu: [[1, 2, 3, -1], [1, 2, 3, "All"]]
    });
    
    $('#vender').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
      var seleccionados = table.rows({ selected: true });
      
      if(!seleccionados.data().length)
        alert("No ha seleccionado ningún producto");
      else{
        seleccionados.every(function(key,data){
          console.log(this.data());

          $('<input>', {
              type: 'hidden',
              value: this.data()[1],
              name: 'ids[]'
          }).appendTo('#form');
          
          //$("#form").submit(); //submiteas el form
        });
      }
  });
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
    <table id="inventario" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Selección articulo</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>&nbsp;Cantidad</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;Marca</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Categoria</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Mi9</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Xiaomi</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>S1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>S2</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>S3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="vender" value="Vender" id="vender">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias voy a revisar y dejo tu calificacion :)

Comment: Amigoa mi no me renderiza los imputs, me podrías dar una mano?

Comment: ¿Por qué le llamas al id $('#example').DataTable( { no deberia ser inventario como lo tienes en el html?

Comment: Logré que funcione, solo falta un gran detalle que solo me selecciona un checkbox, si me cambio a otro se elimina el anterior, solo queda elegido al ultimo checkbox que elegí.

Comment: Para corregir lo de multiple selección solo se debe cambiar style:    'os', por style:    'multi',

Comment: Luis Alfredo Serrano Díaz, le e dado seguimiento a tu respuesta, pero cuando hago click en el boton de vender, no pasa nada! no me envia ningun dato

Answer (score 0):

- A mi me resultó algo más simple... antes de obtener los checkbox
  seleccionados debemos deshacer el formato datatable. En
  una función javascript que guardará los checkbox seleccionados, hacer
  lo siguiente:

  - Deshacer el formato de la tabla (temporalmente) -->   $('#tbl').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  - Obtener con javascript checkbox seleccionados (ahora si aparecerán todos los checkbox)
  - Formatear nuevamente para que el usuario no se de cuenta del cambio    $('#tbl').DataTable({"ordering": true, etc...

  Saludos.