# Datatables + Laravel Blade: Mantener los checkbox sin importar la vista

Tags: laravel, datatables

Actualmente estoy usando datatables, agregué el campo input para seleccionar múltiples registros pero si los registros desaparecen de la vista ya sea porque escribí algo en el buscador o me moví en el paginador cuando hago submit los registros que previamente seleccioné me los elimina y no los envía.

¿Existe una forma de mantener la selección de datatables sin importar en que momento de la vista me encuentre? De manera que cuando envie los datos al backend el array llegue.

```html
<form action="/crear_patrulla" method="post">
  @csrf
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Crear Patrulla"> <br><br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="example" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="funcionario_id[]"></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Departmento</th>
          <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
          <th>Fecha de Actualización</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="funcionario_id[]"></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Departmento</th>
          <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
          <th>Fecha de Actualización</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="funcionario_id[]" value="{{ $funcionario->id }}"></td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->department }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->created_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->updated_at }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: El paginador los borra, es recomendable que no uses el paginador, y si tene muchos registros pued usar un scroll vertical

Comment: Justamente estoy usando datatables porque la cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla no es mucho y no va a crecer gran cantidad en el tiempo.

Comment: Bueno si no es mucho, quedese con el datatable solo inactive el paginador y solucionado

Comment: No es el paginador solamente, si busco un registro y  desaparece la opción que tengo en la tabla tampoco funciona. Deseo conservar la selección sin eliminar el paginador ni el buscador.

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolver el problema utilizando la librería de datatables `select`

Debes cargar este script despues de tu script datatable

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

Y para los estilos puedes cargar en el `<header>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
```

El archivo donde cargas el datatable quedaría de esta forma.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: "select-checkbox",
                targets: 0
            }
        ],
        select: {
            style: "multi",
            selector: "td:first-child"
        }
    });

    $("#crear").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var seleccionados = table.rows({ selected: true }).data();

        if (!seleccionados.length) alert("No ha seleccionado ningún producto");
        else {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < seleccionados.length) {
                $("<input>", {
                    type: "hidden",
                    value: seleccionados[i][1],
                    name: "funcionario_id[]"
                }).appendTo("#form");
                i++;
            }
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Por último tu HTML debe quedar de esta forma:

```html
<form id="form" action="/crear_patrulla" method="post">
  @csrf
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="crear">Crear Patrulla</button> <br><br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Departmento</th>
          <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
          <th>Fecha de Actualización</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Departmento</th>
          <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
          <th>Fecha de Actualización</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->department }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->created_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ $funcionario->updated_at }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

La pregunta ya se encontraba en stackoverflow, lamentablemente la conseguí luego de haber preguntado, sin embargo habían detalles que corregí para este ejemplo, si la comunidad  piensa que debo eliminar el tema no tengo problema.

[Enviar valores de Checkbox de un datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126670/enviar-valores-de-checkbox-de-un-datatables/127037#comment696620_127037)